# Hive - dynamic partition insert fails with less than one hundred partitions

Tags: hadoop, hive, partitioning, hortonworks-data-platform

I am trying to insert records in hive from one table (not partitioned) to another using dynamic partitioning. I've set these hive properties as suggested in few other questions:

```
hive.exec.dynamic.partition=True 
hive.exec.dynamic.partition.pernode=5000
hive.exec.dynamic.partition.pernode=2048
hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict
```

Here you can find the table definitions together with the insert query I am running:

**Non-partitioned table**

```
 CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS dataretention.non_partitioned(
 recordType STRING,
 potentialDuplicate STRING,
 ...
 partDate STRING,
 partHour STRING,
 ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' LOCATION '/tmp/temp-tables/csv/not-partitioned'
```

**Partitioned table**

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS dataretention.partitioned(
 recordType STRING,
 potentialDuplicate STRING,
 ...)
 PARTITIONED BY (partDate STRING, partHour STRING) STORED AS ORC LOCATION '/tmp/temp-tables/partitioned'
```

**Insert query**

```
 INSERT INTO dataretention.partitioned PARTITION(partDate, partHour) SELECT recordType, ... partDate, partHour FROM dataretention.non_partitioned;
```

The file is 1000 record long, the tables have 158 fields. I've tested this first using the hortonworks HDP 2.4 on a sandbox. Since I was thinking about a resource problem, I've moved to a 4-machine m4.xlarge (4-cores, 16 GB ram each) cluster on AWS. I was no able to go over 9 different partitions on the sandbox, and 99 different ones on the cluster. I get a **vertex failed** from Tez four times and after that it quits the job.

Any help or suggestion is really appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: would you please run query `select count(*) from (select distinct partDate, partHour from dataretention.non_partitioned) a;`

Comment: I already checked the number of partitions, which is 1k. I also tried to reduce the number of partitions. On the cluster it works till 90 partitions, on the sandbox 9.

Comment: tez crashes lot many times because of unknown errors e.g. when the cluster capacity is almost full and almost invariably throws vertex failed error. So would you please do `set hive.execution.engine=mr;` and check this again.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but still it was not able to do it. I get a **GC overhead limit exceeded**

Comment: thats much easier to deal with. By increasing `mapreduce.reduce.java.opts` or `mapreduce.map.java.opts` depending on GC in reduce or map stage. try `-Xmx512M` in hive-site.xml or in oozie pass this parameter or in hive script/CLI `set mapreduce.reduce.java.opts=-Xmx512M;` should work.

Comment: Thank you for the useful comments. I am sorry I did not reply soon. I tried increasing the java memory up to 3GB and 6GB respectively, but still I was not able to run the query. I found out that decreasing the number of columns helps (maybe it's related to orc). I settled to a significant lower number of columns removing some of them that were not needed in the final design.

Comment: are you able to run it fine now? less columns less garbage to clean :)